# Could 'frolic' mean homosexual guy?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, word-meaning, interpretation

I searched the meaning of frolic on Google, I found one meaning of frolic is gay. I found it [here](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/frolic).

I don't know if this means homosexual man or not.

One more question is the meaning of below sentence.

> Their frolic in the surf threatened to become ugly.

This is the example given under the definition of **frolic**. The meaning of this sentence is 'The play in the surf looked like dangerous'?

Comment: Can you quote the complete definition you found? "Gay" alone is not a synonym for "frolic".

Comment: Most of the time in a few decades ago, the main meaning of *gay* would be "happy and excited", and it had nothing to do with homosexuality, AFAIK.

Comment: So the definition is "gay or light-hearted recreational activity for diversion or amusement", not just "gay". In this definition, "gay" is an adjective describing the kind of activity we call a "frolic", not a complete definition of the word frolic. As Damkerng says, "gay" is used here in the sense of happy, not homosexual.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it makes an unsupported assumption of what a word might mean.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your confusion seems to arise from the definition provided on that site.

> > [frolic](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/frolic)
> >     n. **gay or light-hearted** recreational activity for diversion or amusement
> >     <*their **frolic** in the surf threatened to become ugly*>

In this definition, *gay* does not mean *homosexual*, but instead it means something like

> [gay](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/gay)
>
> 1. a :  happily excited :  merry
>      <*in a gay mood*>
>      b :  keenly alive and exuberant :  having or inducing high spirits
>      <*a bird's gay spring song*>

So,  "their frolic in the surf threatened to become ugly"
can mean that their **merry activities** on the surf could turn ugly.

Answer (score 2):

> Their frolic in the surf threatened to become ugly.

In this sentence, frolic is used as a noun. Let's look at the definition given by M-W:

1  : a playful or mischievous action

2a :  an occasion or scene of fun :  party

2b :  fun, merriment

We can see that clearly there is nothing to do with a person here so to answer your question "Could 'frolic' mean homosexual guy?". No, frolic does not refer to a person.

Now, that being said, frolic does have a childish or cute connotation. Another example is "prance". People may use these types of words to talk about disdainfully about homosexuals. Example:

> Look at those [derogatory term of choice] frolicking around in the park. What a bunch of [derogatory term].